# Symfony2, bundle, parameters twig

Tags: symfony, bundle, twig

I'm using Symfony2 for a few days, this is my problem, I created a bundle, now I would like to know how do I set the parameters that will be used to twig before rendering the template?
That is, I want to insert a file bundle configuration parameters that specify whether the template should have 1 or 2 columns, or whether it should or not to display the menu in the left column.
I hope I was clear enough.

thanks

Comment: And you tried doing what? this isn't a solve-this-for-me place, this is a please-help-me-I-tried-this-and-it-doesn't-work

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the answer, but I do not want someone to do the code for me, but I want a guide or a methodology on how I can handle this and if it is feasible.
thanks

Comment: Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html; Twig documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

Answer (score 1):

With [twig extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html), you can create your own twig functions, filters, tests or global variables. But Symfony2 also provides an easy way to set global variables: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

```
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        ga_tracking: UA-xxxxx-x
```